# ng-select shows all available options in a list and not just one line?

Tags: angularjs

I tried ng-select and for me it does not correctly show just one line instead it shows a list of all the available options. I then looked at the docs and in multiple browsers and noticed the exact same thing. Specifically the demo that Angulars provide:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

**Using ngValue to bind the model to an array of objects** example

```
<select size="6" name="ngvalueselect" ng-model="data.model" multiple>
  <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" ng-value="option.value">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Can anyone explain why this does not show correctly? Note that I removed the "multiple" in my code. Here's my code:

```
<select size="6"
        name="ngvalueselect"
        ng-model="row.categoryId">
    <option ng-repeat="option in phs.phraseCategory.data"
            ng-value="option.id">
        {{option.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Note that in the AngularJS docs the example after that works fine:

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
  ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id"
  ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>
```

Comment: when you removed multiple attribute, is it working fine? Which code is not working for you ? Can you send code in js fiddle

Comment: It's not working fine when I remove the multiple.  The interesting thing is the second example works and displays okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood your question. 
Setting the size attribute of a selection list lets you display multiple options at the same time.

So first code allows multiple selection. In second implementation as size is 6 it will show the list of 6 options and not one option.

Third implementation is using ng-options. So all the above three implementations are different. Here size is not specified so its showing only one value in select and not the list.